# How to remove certain elements from an array into a new array and leave the others only the original array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

How to write a function to remove certain elements into a new array and leave the original array with only the remaining elements?

the first part is easy using a for loop pushing the even numbers into a new array but mutating the original array to leave only the odd numbers is hard

```
function remove(arr, cb){

 var removed = [];
 var newArr = [];

 for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

   if(cb(arr[i], i, arr)) {
     removed.push(arr[i]);

    } 

 }

 return removed;

}
```

Comment: What are those `certain elements` you're talking about? The even or odd numbered? Can you give an example input array and what the output should look like?

Comment: Can you please add some reference of your expected output and input alongwith what your code is producing?

Comment: if you're going to iterate through the array anyway, just create a new array to replace the original one and add to it just like you did for the `removed` array.

Comment: I'm with @LawrenceJohnson. For both the implemention and use of such a method, it's much easier to reason about simply splitting an array into 2 new arrays by some predicate than a method that generates one array and mutates one of its arguments (side effects... complexity... avoid unless you *measure* hot-path badness).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an `else` statement to fill `newArr` with values that should stay in the original `arr`, then empty it using [`splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) before copying the items from `newArr` back into it.

```
function remove (arr, cb) {
  var removed = [];
  var newArr = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (cb(arr[i], i, arr)) {
      removed.push(arr[i]);
    } else {
      newArr.push(arr[i]);
    }
  }

  arr.splice(0);

  for (var i = 0; i < newArr.length; i++) {
    arr.push(newArr[i]);
  }

  return removed;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stackoverflow!

Personally, I'd avoid anything that mutates an input parameter, as this increases code complexity and makes it hard to reason about what's happening from the calling side.

Instead, I'd write a method that returns an array of two arrays. This can be easily split into two variables at the calling end using by using array destructuring.

See the example below:

```js
const splitArr = (arr, pred) =>
  arr.reduce(
    (prev, curr, idx) => {
      prev[+pred(curr, idx, arr)].push(curr);
      return prev;
    }, [[], []]
  );

// usage //

const myArr = [1, 2, 3, 4];
const [arr1, arr2] = splitArr(myArr, x => x > 2);
console.log(arr1);
console.log(arr2);
```

Because `pred` is a function that returns a boolean value, we can co-erce this value to `0` or `1` using `+someBoolean`. We can then use this value as an index to decide into which of the two output arrays the value should be pushed.

Answer (score 0):

In modern JavaScript apps we do not mutate arrays we create new array, this avoids side effects, so what we do is create two new arrays

```
const split = (source, conditionFunc) = [ source.filter(i => conditionFunc(i)), source.filter(i => !conditionFunc(i))];
```

Then you have an array of two arrays of the values that meed condition and those that don't and you have not caused any side effects.

```
const odssAndEvens = split(source, i => i % 2 === 1);
```

Or with reduce so you don't iterate the array twice

```
const split = (source, conditionFunc) = source.reduce((results, item) => {
  if (conditionFunc(item)) {
    results[0].push(item);
  } else {
    results[1].push(item);
  }
  return results;
}, [[],[]]);
```

Comment: A better proposal for sure, but it really isn't necessary to iterate the `source` array twice. Did you mean `don't mutate` instead of `do mutate` near the start of this answer?

Comment: Added a reduce that iterates once

Answer (score 0):

You were definitely on the right track with your solution, a couple tweaks and we can make it very readable and also very easy to work with. I tried to keep the format of what it looked like you were doing.

I do take advantage of destructuring here, this could be returned as just an object, and then reference the properties.

```
const myArr = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];

const splitItems = (arr, logicFunc) => {
    let secondSet = []

    const firstSet = arr.filter(v => {
      if (logicFunc(v)) return true
      else secondSet.push(v)
    })

    return { firstSet, secondSet }
}

const myLogicFunc = v => (v < 3 || v == 9)
const { firstSet, secondSet } = splitItems(myArr, myLogicFunc)

console.log(`My first set: ${firstSet}`) // My first set: 0,1,2,9
console.log(`My second set: ${secondSet}`) // My second set: 3,4,5,6,7,8,10

/* OR without destructuring:
const myArrays = splitItems(myArr, myLogicFunc)

console.log(`My first set: ${myArrays.firstSet}`)
console.log(`My second set: ${myArrays.secondSet}`)
*/
```

Please let me know if you have any questions